# Message handling: Should a test/spec do it?

Tags: unit-testing, swift, mocks

I am currently implementing an app that uses an architecture based on features & usecases and message sending.

Features are created with message handler passed in.
To test the feature, a handler intercepting the resulting message, must be passed in.

I came up with 2 solutions, both currently being present in the project's code:

1. use an object implementing the message handling protocol and offering a callback.

   ```
   import Quick
   import Nimble
   @testable import LibExample

   class Mock {
       class MessageHandler: MessageHandling {

          init(callBack: @escaping (Message) -> ()) {
               self.callBack = callBack
           }

           let callBack: (Message) -> ()

           func handle(msg: Message) {
               callBack(msg)
           }
       }
   }

   class SettingsFeatureSpec: QuickSpec {
       override func spec() {
           describe("the SettingsFeature UseCase") {
               var sut: SettingsFeature!

               var messageHandler: Mock.MessageHandler!
               var receivedModes: [TransportOption]!

               beforeEach {
                   receivedModes = []
                   messageHandler = Mock.MessageHandler {
                       if case .feature(.settings(.useCase(.transport(.action(.didActivate(let m)))))) = $0         {
                           receivedModes.append(m)
                       }
                   }
                   sut = SettingsFeature(with: messageHandler)
               }

               afterEach {
                   receivedModes = nil
                   messageHandler = nil
                   sut = nil
               }

               it("switches transport modes") {
                   sut.handle(feature: .settings(.useCase(.transport(.action(.activate(.udp))))))
                   sut.handle(feature: .settings(.useCase(.transport(.action(.activate(.tcp))))))
                   sut.handle(feature: .settings(.useCase(.transport(.action(.activate(.tls))))))
                   sut.handle(feature: .settings(.useCase(.transport(.action(.activate(.udp))))))

                   expect(receivedModes) == [.udp, .tcp, .tls, .udp]
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. have the test/spec implement the the message handling

   ```
   import Quick
   import Nimble
   @testable import LibExample

   class UserHandlingSpec: QuickSpec, MessageHandling {

       var loggedInUser:User!
       var loggedOutUser:User!

       func handle(msg: Message) {
            switch msg {
           case .feature(.userHandling(.useCase(.login(.action(.logInConfirmed(let user)))))):
               self.loggedInUser = user
           case .feature(.userHandling(.useCase(.logout(.action(.logOutConfirmed(let user)))))):
               self.loggedOutUser = user
           default:
               break
           }
       }

       override func spec() {
           describe("the UserHandling Feature") {
               var sut: UserHandlingFeature!

               beforeEach {
                   sut = UserHandlingFeature(with: self)
               }

               afterEach {
                   sut = nil
                   self.loggedOutUser = nil
                   self.loggedInUser = nil
               }

               it("logs in user"){
                   sut.handle(feature: .userHandling(.useCase(.login(.action(.logIn("pinky", "password"))))))

                   expect(self.loggedInUser.name) == "pinky"
               }

               it("logs out user"){
                   sut.handle(feature: .userHandling(.useCase(.logout(.action(.logOut(User(name:"the brain")))))))

                   expect(self.loggedOutUser.name) == "the brain"
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Which one would be the preferred way and why?

Comment: Have you tried either of these solutions? Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Mast: yes, I did